# ConnectionKit & iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm still getting my feet wet with the iPhone SDK, but I'm wondering if it would be possible to get the ConnectionKit framework working for an iPhone app. I know it was developed for the desktop OS, so I'm not sure what sort of dependencies it has and whether or not it could be shoehorned into the iPhone OS.

In my case, I would like to use its FTP functionality, though having access to this entire framework could prove useful for future projects as well.

Any ideas or experience trying this?

In case it helps, here's the official ConnectionKit site: http://opensource.utr-software.com/connection/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site was a little light on documentation.

The big question is what Cocoa classes it depends on. Since it is doesn't include any UI code, it should be based on Foundation classes. Foundation in Cocoa Touch is similar to, but not exactly the same as on OS X. Just check out what classes it uses.

The other obstacle is building the framework as a static library. Since the iPhone does not support frameworks/dynamic libraries, you have to build a static library to use it in your code.

That should help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary issues. One is static library and other is NSHost class that is supported by cocoa - but not cocoa touch. First one is doable - but the second one is doable if and only if you are familiar with Mac OS networking internals.