# Is there a way to delete a file/folder from a ftp server with CFNetwork?

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, sockets, cfnetwork

I searched the web for a solution, but it seems that there is no easy one. Now, there must be a way of course, even if that means that I need to send the RMDIR command to the ftp myself. However my sockets/streams knowledge is not very wide and I'm not sure where should I start.

PS: Already tried `CFURLDestroyResource` which doesn't work for folder deletion. Apple states that CFNetwork doesn't directly support deletion for FTP scheme/protocol (only for HTTP) so I guess I have to somehow implement it myself, but again, where should I start?

Comment: Just so you know, Apple strongly dislikes FTP. The FTP client in the Finder is severely crippled, and rightfully so. It doesn't let you delete things when using FTP, so I don't know how much success you'll have in iOS.

Comment: I know about that, I also know that FTP is a crappy *unsecure* (yeah, the user and password are sent without encryption) protocol and that Apple (naturally) hates it. However, unfortunately for us, programmers, it *does exist* and sometimes it's not us who decide whether to use it or not ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, **CFURLDestroyResource** works. The problem is, in order to delete a directory , in ftp protocol, the directory should be empty.

So basically you need to enumerate all files & directories in that directory and delete them first.

Also be careful, your URL should end with "/" if you are deleting a directory.

instead of ftp://user:pass@example.com/somedir you should use ftp://user:pass@example.com/somedir/

Comment: OK, will try it with an empty dir when I get home.

Comment: Just tested, and indeed, `CFURLDestroyResource` works just fine with directories too, they just need to be empty. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This open-source project](https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit) supports FTP in Cocoa; however it [appears it might require some hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215848/connectionkit-iphone-sdk) to make it work for Cocoa Touch.

Regardless of whether you can use it as is, the FTP protocol implementation therein may help get you on your way.

Comment: I'm not looking for a library but I'll try to see if I can locate the code that does the deletion of the file and more important if I can do the same on iOS (from previous experiences, I found that there are several differences when using CFNetwork in iOS comparing with OSX)